Setting up React with DRF?
Currently, I'm following some lessons on my course and building a social media website project for assessment in future. I am currently stuck with getting my React App built within a Django Rest Framework App to display even the default React page when hosting Live Server, I will link my repo below if it helps I feel like I have gone in circles now as I'm not fully clued in on a full stack project yet (hence trying to get it together). Very much appreciate if anyone could take a look and help me out. I am a bit of a noob so may be obvious and I'm missing something entirely.
https://github.com/conor-timmis/Better-You
So far I've been dabbling with the Views & urls of the main app, but not sure where to go from there. Lessons have not really explained this so much, only creating the apps separately then linking them together, but mention building within one repo instead with a full app but I am building from scratch so that's not really an option. (I have tried building my app and putting them into static as I read that in another thread but didn't have any luck with that).

To serve the React app with Django, you will need to compile it (usually done with npx build) then serve the compiled js files like you would any other app.  in development, it's much easier treat the React server and Django backend as two separate apps.
